# Phong material on a .obj model not reacting to area light in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add a phong material to my .obj model along with a shader Area light, However i tried to use Meshface material using array to load both materials but the model completely disappears when i do so.

The scenario works when i use either of them but not both together, is there anyway to overcome this issue ?

Here is the [DEMO](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andyram08/neavik/master/newarea.html):

CODE:

```
// area light
var lightColor = 0xffffff;
var lightIntensity = 1;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 50);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: lightColor,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.7,
    side: THREE.FrontSide
});

areaLight = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

areaLight.position.set(0, 25, -25);
areaLight.rotation.set(0, 0, 0);
areaLight.scale.set(1, 1, 1);
scene.add(areaLight);


var Black = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x000000,


    })
    // wireframe hack
areaLight.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    wireframe: true
})));

// areaLight verts
var vertices = areaLight.geometry.vertices;
var verts = [];
verts.push(vertices[0]);
verts.push(vertices[1]);
verts.push(vertices[3]);
verts.push(vertices[2]);

// uniforms
var uniforms = {
    color: {
        type: "c",
        value: new THREE.Color(0xaaaadd)
    },

    lightColor: {
        type: "c",
        value: areaLight.material.color
    },
    lightIntensity: {
        type: "f",
        value: lightIntensity
    },
    lightverts: {
        type: "v3v",
        value: verts
    },
    lightMatrixWorld: {
        type: "m4",
        value: areaLight.matrixWorld
    }
};

// attributes
var attributes = {};

// material
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    attributes: attributes,
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex_shader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment_shader').textContent,
    shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});


var onError = function(xhr) {};
THREE.Loader.Handlers.add(/\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());
var mtl1Loader = new THREE.MTLLoader();

mtl1Loader.setBaseUrl('neavik/newmail/');
mtl1Loader.setPath('neavik/newmail/');
mtl1Loader.load('chandelier.mtl', function(materials) {

    materials.preload();

    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
    objLoader.setMaterials(materials);

    objLoader.setPath('neavik/newmail/');
    objLoader.load('chandelier.obj', function(object4) {

        object4.castShadow = true;
        object4.receiveShadow = true;
        object4.updateMatrix();
        object4.position.set(40, 28, 40); //(0,-5,0.5);
        object4.scale.x = 0.09;
        object4.scale.y = 0.05;
        object4.scale.z = 0.09



        var mats = [];
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0x000000
        }));
        mats.push(material);
        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats);



        object4.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (child.material.name == "chandelier_Outside") {

                    child.material = Black; // When i use faceMaterial here the object disappears
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }


            }


        });
        scene.add(object4);
    });
})

// plane geometry
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 200);
geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX(-Math.PI / 2));

// plane
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.y = -0.1;
scene.add(mesh);

// torus knot
var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry(10, 4, 256, 32, 1, 3, 1);

// mesh
mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
mesh.position.set(0, 28, 0);
scene.add(mesh);

}
```

The main issue section

```
var mats = [];
        mats.push(new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: 0x000000
        }));
        mats.push(material);
        var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(mats);



        object4.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                if (child.material.name == "chandelier_Outside") {

                    child.material = Black; // When i use faceMaterial here the object disappears
                    child.castShadow = true;
                    child.receiveShadow = true;
                }


            }


        });
        scene.add(object4);
    });
})
```

Area light reference:http://jsfiddle.net/hh74z2ft/1/

Expected result is similar to this image that even the chandelier should be illuminated like torusknot along with phongness [no phongness in this image ]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mE1Ar.jpg)

Comment: what are you after here? Some faces of that chandelier should be shaded by the phong-material and others by the areaLight-material? Can you maybe explain what the intended result would be?

Comment: @MartinSchuhfuß i just wanted to retain both materials on chandelier so that it can possess a phong material as well as this area light shader, i updated an image on how it works when i use only one material ?

Comment: check the objects normals

Comment: how can i add two materials to a single object ? multimaterial ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if I understood you correctly, this will not work.

A material (among other things) defines how a given fragment of a triangle will be shaded. There can always be only one material for any given triangle. The face-material is for handling the case where you want to render different faces with different materials, but it's still just one material per triangle.

There is a concept in three.js named multiMaterial (have a look at `THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject()`). But that will simply create multiple meshes with the same geometry and different materials, so every triangle will get rendered twice, once with every material.

Now the Problem is that the AreaLight implementation has it's very own concept of how the light is represented (via shader-uniforms), and that is completely different from how the phong-material works. So, even if you did somehow add a phong-material to the object to get the specular reflections, the phong-material wouldn't know how to deal with the area-light source (it wouldn't even know that there is any light in the scene).

In order to get the behaviour you like to see you would need to add a specular term (the calculation-formula for specular reflections of the surface) to the fragment-shader and maybe some uniforms to control it's behaviour. This is a really complicated thing to do, especially for area-lights (if it were easy, we'd already have it in three.js).

However, there is some work being done based on latest research in that field, you might want to have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8718) and the [demo here](http://groovemechanic.net/three.js.halffloat/examples/webgl_lights_rectarealight.html). There is also a pull-request for this [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/9234).